# How to iterate over a big table concurrently?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use threading to speed up a function that iterate over every row in a big table.

My current implementation is to find all the "cursors" beforehand with the following SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(x.id) FROM
  (SELECT id FROM big_table WHERE state = 3 AND id > %s ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000)
```

I iterate over the table with this SQL, each time using the last id as the cursor for the next query.

After getting these "cursors", I can start spawning threads.

But this *cursor finding* step becomes the new bottleneck, it turns out to be very slow.

What are some other ways I can use to split the "iteration" to small chunks that I can assign to threads?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with splitting it up? Some kind of pagination?

Comment: @frlan 

My current implementation is just like when doing pagination with cursor, the only difference is that I query the pages with several threads.
But this turns out to be slow, so I'm looking for a better way to iterate over the table with multiple threads.
It doesn't have to be some kind of pagination.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data at the end? It looks like sorting the complete table and printing out just every 10k item

Comment: I was looping through the table like you said, but I want to make it faster.

Comment: Your subselect will iterate over nearly complete dataset everytime you are running it. I'd add an index on state and id and run in one run.